# Exception Filters returning an empty body in asp.net-core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The following Exception Filter redirects exceptions to my specific error page.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class FrontofficeControllerExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    protected readonly ILogger<FrontofficeController> _logger;
    protected readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    protected readonly IModelMetadataProvider _modelMetadataProvider;

    public FrontofficeControllerExceptionFilterAttribute(ILogger<FrontofficeController> logger, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.ExceptionHandled) return;

        Exception ex = context.Exception;
        var result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "ApplicationError" };

        context.ExceptionHandled = true; // mark exception as handled
        context.Result = result;
    }
}
```

After migrating my web app to asp.net core 1.1 the result is a blank page: the body of the response is empty and Content-Length is zero. This is the response received on the client

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcaW50ZXJhaC52aXN1YWxzdHVkaW8uY29tXEludmVudGFyaW9cTWFpblxTb3VyY2VcRnJvbnRvZmZpY2Vcc3JjXEZyb250b2ZmaWNl?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2016 14:49:53 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

have anyone experienced a similar problem and why?
thankyou for any comment

Comment: I drop here an update if someone has the same problem: 
1) starting with a fresh and empty new app with aspnetcore 1.0.1 the page is rendered correctly
2) commenting the row 'context.ExceptionHandled = true;' the page is rendered  

so it really seems that the problem is with asp.net core.1.1 and  'context.ExceptionHandled'

Answer (score 1):

the behavior is confirmed by github aspnet/mvc team. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5594#issuecomment-265866653

at the moment, the only solution is to render directly an HTML response. in this case marking ExceptionHandled = true works as expected.

```
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.ExceptionHandled = true; // mark exception as handled
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html").ToString();
        var home = string.Format("{0}://{1}", context.HttpContext.Request.Scheme,context.HttpContext.Request.Host);
        var htmlString ="<h2>SI E' VERIFICATO UN ERRORE INATTESO</h><br/><br/>";
        context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(htmlString, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```